# How does a proof of work limit of `~uint256(0) >> 20` translate into a difficulty of `1 / 2^12`?

Tags: litecoin, development, difficulty, hash

In the Litecoin source it is written:

```
static CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimit(~uint256(0) >> 20); // Litecoin: starting difficulty is 1 / 2^12
```

How does that compute? `~uint256(0) >> 20` is `0x00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`. Hashes have an equal probability of being any given number, so the chance of getting a valid Litecoin hash (i.e. one that is smaller than this number) is `0x00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff / 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` = `1 / 2^20`, **not** `1 / 2^12`. Is this a typo in the Litecoin source code or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: A good way to remember it is that a difficulty of 1 means an average of `2^32` hashes are needed to mine one block, and it scales linearly from there.  This convention comes from Bitcoin where the minimum difficulty is in fact 1.

Comment: Hi. At recent source, there is no CBigNum, what it have been changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the terminology on [Litecoin's wiki](https://litecoin.info/Difficulty), `~uint256(0) >> 20` is the target, and `1 / 2^12` is (approximately) the difficulty. You can see that by running the following in Python (or anything that can handle calculations on large numbers).

```
target = 0x00000fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff # or 2**236-1
diff = 0xFFFF * 2**208 / target
print(diff) # 0.00024413689970970154
print(1/2**12) # 0.000244140625
```

I believe the `1 / 2^20` figure you calculated is the probability that each hash will succeed, which is not the same as (although related to) the difficulty.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't realize they had a convention for what the difficulty is. That does elucidate matters.

Comment: Hi. At recent source, there is no CBigNum, what it have been changed?